# How can I style Googles "save to drive" button

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Google has a save to drive api that i am using for a project. I am curious to see if it is possible to style the button provided. In the docs it says that you can create an element and overlay it ontop of the button but i cant seem to find any working examples.

Their working documentation is here

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/savetodrive

This is the div that we have to work with

```
              <div
                className="g-savetodrive"
                data-src={file}
                data-filename={file}
                data-sitename="site.com"
              />
```

The button looks very dated and doesnt fit well with the current styling of my site.

i am able to create a div and make it click throughable with pointer-events: none

but the issue is that i cant change the size of the save to drive button,

Comment: You can't do this. Google has made it so you cannot do anything past what their documentation states you can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The google drive icon is an Iframe, in out css file we can grab the Iframe and change the width

```
iframe {
    width: 230px !important;
}
```

doing this will change the width of the icon, which is great... since by default it is pretty small. But now how do we style it?

We have to create an 'overlay' we can create a div with position of absolute, inside of the div we can add a styled button

```
        <div
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            pointerEvents: "none",
          }}
        >
          <Button onPress={() => {}}>overlay button</Button>
        </div>
```

now this button sits on top of the save to drive button. This is an over simplified version but just a base on how to do it and to show it is possible and easy

by adding pointerEvents:"none" we are able to "click through" the button, so the google drive button instead is actually being clicked!